# Is there a more intuitive proof of the halting problem's undecidability than diagonalization?

Tags: computability, proof-techniques, undecidability, halting-problem, intuition

I understand the proof of the undecidability of the halting problem (given for example in Papadimitriou's textbook), based on diagonalization.

While the proof is *convincing* (I understand each step of it), it is not *intuitive* to me in the sense that I don't see how someone would derive it, starting from the problem alone.

In the book, the proof goes like this: "suppose $M_H$ solves the halting problem on an input $M;x$, that is, decides whether Turing machine $M$ halts for input $x$. Construct a Turing machine $D$ that takes a Turing machine $M$ as input, runs $M_H(M;M)$ and reverses the output." It then goes on to show that $D(D)$ cannot produce a satisfactory output.

It is the seemingly arbitrary construction of $D$, particularly the idea of feeding $M$ to itself, and then $D$ to itself, that I would like to have an intuition for. What led people to define those constructs and steps in the first place?

Does anyone have an explanation on how someone would reason their way into the diagonalization argument (or some other proof), if they did not know that type of argument to start with?

**Addendum given the first round of answers:**

So the first answers point out that proving the undecidability of the halting problem was something based on Cantor and Russell's previous work and development of the diagonalization problem, and that starting "from scratch" would simply mean having to rediscover that argument.

Fair enough. However, even if we accept the diagonalization argument as a well-understood given, I still find there is an "intuition gap" from it to the halting problem. Cantor's proof of the real numbers uncountability I actually find fairly intuitive; Russell's paradox even more so.

What I still don't see is what would motivate someone to define $D(M)$ based on $M$'s "self-application" $M;M$, and then again apply $D$ to itself. That seems to be less related to diagonalization (in the sense that Cantor's argument did not have something like it), although it obviously works well with diagonalization once you define them.

**P.S.**

@babou summarized what was troubling me better than myself: "The problem with many versions of the proof is that the constructions seem to be pulled from a magic hat."

Comment: Consider the possibility that *any* proof of the existence of uncountable sets will have to be somewhat counterintuitive, even if we get used to the fact that they are *correct*. Consider also the possibility that this question (if properly rephrased) belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Check this question, for instance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374967/alternate-proofs-other-than-diagonalization-and-topological-nested-sets-for-un

Comment: Cantor found the diagonalization argument, and now we cannot unlearn it: [Aus dem Paradies, das Cantor uns geschaffen, soll uns niemand vertreiben können](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradise).

Comment: After further thought, I have to ask why you think this is so different from Russell's paradox. Russell's paradox even _looks_ the same if we use the notation $S(X)$ to mean $X \in S$ (i.e. think of sets as being functions whose values are `true` or `false`). Then Russell's paradox is to define `D(M) = not M(M)`, and then consider `D(D)`.

Comment: ... maybe the key idea you're missing is that you can think of TMs as having a three-valued logic, "accept, reject, doesn't halt". Applying $M_H$ would let us eliminate the "doesn't halt" cases.

Comment: Diagonalization is a *standard technique*. Sure there was a time when it wasn't known but it's been standard for a lot of time now, so your argument is simply due to your ignorance (I don't want to be rude, is a fact: you didn't know all the other proofs that use such a technique and hence find it odd the first time you see it. When you've seen it 50 times you'll probably be able to understand how it can be applied in a new situation).

Comment: You are correct about the D(M) -> M(M) arbitrariness, yet it is true of the Turing machine.

Comment: @Hurkyl: you are right, it is not so different from Russell's paradox. It's the bit with the inputs (which Russell's paradox doesn't involve) that seems the tricky part for me. I think Ilmari's answer below clarifies that part very well.

Comment: Maybe you would read my exchange of comments with Luke Mathieson
(following his answer). His answer explains historically why Turing
used self-application (one thing you ask for in your question). That
seems to be pretty-much how mathematicians perceived the issues at the
time. My own answer tries to give a very simple proof that does not
use it (or at least shows it is not essential) which is another thing
you ask for, quite different. Possibly, I might make it even simpler than in my
answer. Why teachers still use Turing's proof is a sociological and
pedagogical (?!) issue. cc @HendrikJan

Comment: This does not help much with intuition, but it's so much fun I'll post it anyway: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/loopsnoop.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your edit, you write:

> What I still don't see is what would motivate someone to define $D(M)$ based on $M$'s "self-application" $M;M$, and then again apply $D$ to itself. That seems to be less related to diagonalization (in the sense that Cantor's argument did not have something like it), although it obviously works well with diagonalization once you define them.

A common "popular" summarization of Turing's proof goes something like this:

> "If we had a machine $M_H$ that could decide whether another Turing machine halts or not, we could use this to construct another machine $D$ that, given a Turing machine $M$, would halt if and only if $M$ did *not* halt.  But then we could pass $D$ as input to itself, and thus obtain a paradox: this machine would halt if and only if it did not halt!"

Now, it's easy to see that the summarization above glosses over an important detail — the halting of the Turing machine $M$ also depends on its input, which we have not specified!
But this issue can be fixed easily enough: we just need to have $D$ pick some suitable input $x_M$ for each input machine $M$, before passing them both to $M_H$.

What's a suitable choice for $x_M$, given that we ultimately want to derive a contradiction?  Well, a natural choice is suggested directly by the "handwavy" proof above, where we ultimately obtain the contradiction by running the machine $D$ on itself.

Thus, for the behavior of $D$ to really be paradoxical in this case, i.e. when invoked as $D(D)$, what we want is for the halting of $D(M)$ to depend on the behavior of $M$ *when invoked as $M(M)$*.  This way, we'll obtain the contradiction we want by setting $M = D$.

Mind you, this is not the only choice; we could also have derived the same contradiction by, say, constructing a machine $D'$ such that $D'(M)$ halts if and only if $M(D')$ (rather than $M(M)$) does not halt.  But, whereas it's clear that the machine $D$ can easily duplicate its input before passing it to $M_H$, it's not quite so immediately obvious how to construct a machine $D'$ that would invoke $M_H$ with its own code as the input.  Thus, using this $D'$ instead of $D$ would needlessly complicate the proof, and make it less intuitive.

Comment: Wow, you really grokked my question! That is *exactly* the type of story I was looking for! Still reading everything, but this looks like it would be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

It may be simply that it's mistaken to think that someone would reason their way to this argument without making a similar argument at some point prior, in a "simpler" context.

Remember that Turing knew Cantor's diagonalisation proof of the uncountability of the reals. Moreover his work is part of a history of mathematics which includes Russell's paradox (which uses a diagonalisation argument) and Gödel's first incompleteness theorem (which uses a diagonalisation argument). In fact, Gödel's result is deeply related to the proof of undecidability of the Halting Problem (and hence the negative answer to Hilbert's Entscheidungsproblem).

So my contention is that your question is in a sense badly founded and that you *can't* reach the Halting Problem without going past the rest (or something remarkably similar) first. While we show these things to students without going through the history, if you were a working mathematician it seems unlikely that you go from nothing to Turing Machines without anything in between - the whole point of them was to formalise computation, a problem many people had been working on for decades at that point.

Cantor didn't even use diagonalisation in his first proof of the uncountability of the reals, if we take publication dates as an approximation of when he thought of the idea (not always a reliable thing), it took him about 17 years from already knowing that the reals were uncountable, to working out the diagonalisation argument.

In reference to the "self-application" in the proof that you mention, this is also an integral part of Russell's paradox (which entirely depends upon self-reference), and Gödel's first incompleteness theorem is like the high-powered version of Russell's paradox. The proof of the undecidability of the Halting Problem is so heavily informed by Gödel's work that it's hard to imagine getting there without it, hence the idea of "self-application" is already part of the background knowledge you need to get to the Halting Problem. Similarly, Gödel's work is a reworking of Russell's paradox, so you don't get there without the other (note that Russell was not the first to observe a paradox like this, so prototypes of the diagonalisation argument has been around in formal logic since about 600BCE). Both Turing and Gödel's work (the bits we're talking about here that is) can be viewed as increasingly powerful demonstrations of the problems with self-reference, and how it is embedding in mathematics. So once again, it's very difficult to suggest that these ideas at the level Turing was dealing with them came *a priori*, they were the culmination of millennia's work in parts of philosophy, mathematics and logic.

This self-reference is also part of Cantor's argument, it just isn't presented in such an unnatural language as Turing's more fundamentally logical work. Cantor's diagonalisation can be rephrased as a selection of elements from the power set of a set (essentially part of Cantor's Theorem). If we consider the set of (positive) reals as subsets of the naturals (note we don't really need the digits to be ordered for this to work, it just makes a simpler presentation) and claim there is a surjection from the naturals to the reals, then we can produce an element of the power set (i.e. a real) that is not in the image of the surjection (and hence derive a contradiction) by take this element to be the set of naturals who are not in their own image under the surjection. Once we phrase it this way, it's much easier to see that Russell's paradox is really the naïve set theory version of the same idea.

Comment: Yes, it seems the whole point of Turing was to recreate circularity (from which comes diagonalization) using machines, for the sake of introducing some abstract idea of *time*, with which to talk about finiteness in a new way.

Comment: Maybe you can enlighten me, as I am not familiar with some of these
proofs. I can understand that these proofs can be cunducted using self
referencing. I can even believe (though it might need a proof) that
there is always some self reference to be found in whatever structure
is constructed for the purpose. But I do not see the need to use it
explicitly to conduct the proof to its conclusion. You can rephrase
Cantor's argument that way, but you do not have to. And I do not see
why you have to do it for the halting problem. I may have missed a
step, but which?

Comment: To make my previous remark clearer, **the original question is**: "*Is
there a more intuitive proof of the halting problem's undecidability
...*". I am omitting the end, since my feeling is that the OP complains
mainly about the lack of intuition. I believe that there is indeed a
more intuitive proof, not using self-reference. You may think that
using that proof is pedagogically unwise (as not related to Russell's
and Gödel's work), but if it answer the question asked, what is the
point of rejecting it. You seem to be denying the question rather than answering it.

Comment: @babou I think the problem here is that we're answering different questions. The OP was not well phrased in that regard I guess. The repeated question in the body of the OP seem to me to be "how did someone ever think of the diagonalisation argument to prove ..." (paraphrased of course), and that "the constructions seem to be pulled from a magic hat".

Comment: @babou, also to elaborate a little, with a proper keyboard, I don't think one way or another is necessarily pedagogically useful (it would depend heavily on context). In fact, for most modern CS courses, it's probably better to do it without the diagonalisation argument, most CS students just aren't mathematically inclined enough any more to know the background that would make it easier to understand, but I was definitely answering the question that ended the original body text: ...

Comment: "Does anyone have an explanation on how someone would reason their way into the diagonalization argument (or some other proof), if they did not know that type of argument to start with?" - in which I admittedly missed the "(or some other proof)" part. So my answer is then that you don't, the choice to use that argument was deeply tied in with the mathematics that was current and inspirational to the work, hence that the question "how to you make up that proof from nothing?" is misguided because it denies the historical context.

Comment: "Diagonalization argument" is hazily defined. Kernel idea: given an
infinite enumeration of characteristic functions, you can make a new
one not in the list. One way: flip the diagonal. Convenient, but **not
necessary**. With that you define a device that cannot be a Turing
machine by construction and prove it is a Turing machine from a wrong
assumption (∃$M_H$). Given this inconsistency, you can apply a∧¬a⇒b
and get any paradox you may desire.  What I am trying to say is that I
am not really convinced by the importance of the diagonal , hence of
self-application, and the liar paradox.

Comment: @babou I guess it depends what you mean by important. Important to the truth of the uncomputability of the halting problem, no it would seem not. Important to how to get the particular proof that Turing used and most texts repeat, most definitely.

Comment: @LukeMathieson "it took him about 17 years from already knowing that the reals were uncountable, to working out the diagonalisation argument" How did he know the reals were uncountable without diagonalisation?

Comment: @user76284 After spending a while bashing my mediocre German against the original paper, I worked out there's actually [just a Wikipedia page about it](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor's_first_set_theory_article). Long story short, it's a proof that the reals are everywhere dense.

Answer (score 13):

## Self application is not a necessary ingredient of the proof

### In a nutshell

**If there is a Turing machine $H$ that solves
the halting problem, then from that machine we can build another Turing
machine $L$ with a halting behavior (halting characteristic function)
that cannot be the halting behavior of any Turing machine.**

The paradox built on the self applied function $D$ (called $L$ in this answer - sorry about notation inconsistencies) is not a necessary
ingredient of the proof, but a device usable with the construction of
one specific contradiction, hiding what seems to be the "real purpose" of the construction. That is probably why it is not
intuitive.

It seems more direct to show that there is only a denumerable number
of halting behaviors (no more than Turing machines), that can be
defined as characteristic halting functions associated with each Turing
machine. One can define constructively a characteristic halting
function not in the list, and build from it, and from a machine $H$
that solves the halting problem, a machine $L$ that has that new
characteristic halting function. But since, by construction, it is not
the characteristic halting function of a Turing machine, $L$ cannot be
one. Since $L$ is built from $H$ using Turing machine building
techniques, $H$ cannot be a Turing machine.

The self-application of $L$ to itself, used in many proofs, is a way
to show the contradiction. But it works only when the impossible
characteristic halting function is built from the diagonal of the list
of Turing permitted characteristic halting functions, by flipping this
diagonal (exchanging $0$ and $1$). But there are infinitely many other ways
of building a new characteristic halting function. Then
non-Turing-ness can no longer be evidenced with a liar paradox (at
least not simply). The self-application construction is not intuitive
because it is not essential, but it looks slick when pulled out of the
magic hat.

Basically, $L$ is not a Turing machine because it is designed from
the start to have a halting behavior that is not that of a Turing
machine, and that can be shown more directly, hence more intuitively.

**Note**: It may be that, for any constructive choice of the
  impossible characteristic halting function, there is a computable
  reordering of the Turing machine enumeration such that it becomes
  the diagonal ( I do not know). But, imho, this does not change the
  fact that self-application is an indirect proof technique that is
  hiding a more intuitive and interesting fact.

## Detailed analysis of the proofs

I am not going to be historical (but thanks to those who are, I enjoy
it), but I am only trying to work the intuitive side.

I think that [the presentation given @vzn](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42819/is-there-a-more-intuitive-proof-of-the-halting-problems-undecidability-than-dia/42821#42821), which I did encounter a long
time ago (I had forgotten), is actually rather intuitive, and even
explains the name diagonalization. I am repeating it in details only because I
feel @vzn did not emphasize enough its simplicity.

My purpose is to have an intuitive way to retrieve the proof, knowing
that of Cantor. The problem with many versions of the proof is that the
constructions seem to be pulled from a magic hat.

The proof that I give is not exactly the same as in the question,
but it is correct, as far as I can see. If I did not make a mistake, it
is intuitive enough since I could retrieve it after more years than I
care to count, working on very different issues.

### The case of the subsets of $\mathbb N$ (Cantor)

The proof of Cantor assumes (it is only an hypothesis) that there is an enumeration of the
subsets of the integers, so that all such subset $S_j$ can be
described by its characteristic function $C_j(i)$ which is $1$ if
$i\in S_j$ and is $0$ otherwise.

This may be seen as a table $T$, such that $T[i,j]=C_j(i)$

Then, considering the diagonal, we build a characteristic function $D$
such that $D(i)=\overline{T[i,i]}$, i.e. it is identical to the
diagonal of the table with every bit flipped to the other value.

There is nothing special about the diagonal, except that it is an easy
way to get a characteristic function $D$ that is different from all
others, and that is all we need.

Hence, the subset characterized by $D$ cannot be in the enumeration.
Since that would be true of any enumeration, there cannot be an
enumeration that enumerates all the subsets of $\mathbb N$.

This is admittedly, according to the initial question, fairly
intuitive. Can we make the proof of the halting problem as intuitive?

### The case of the halting problem (Turing)

We assume we have an enumeration of Turing machines (which we know is
possible). The halting behavior of a Turing machine $M_j$ can be
described by its characteristic halting function $H_j(i)$ which is $1$ if
$M_j$ halts on input $i$ and is $0$ otherwise.

This may be seen as a table $T$, such that $T[i,j]=H_j(i)$

Then, considering the diagonal, we build a characteristic halting function $D$
such that $D(i)=\overline{T[i,i]}$, i.e. it is identical to the
diagonal of the table with every bit flipped to the other value.

There is nothing special about the diagonal, except that it is an easy
way to get a characteristic halting function $D$ that is different from all
others, and that is all we need (see note at the bottom).

Hence, the halting behavior characterized by $D$ cannot be that of a
Turing machine in the enumeration. Since we enumerated them all, we
conclude that there is no Turing machine with that behavior.

*No halting oracle so far, and no computability hypothesis*: We know
nothing of the computability of $T$ and of the functions $H_j$.

Now suppose we have a Turing machine $H$ that can solve the halting
problem, such that $H(i,j)$ always halts with $H_j(i)$ as result.

We want to prove that, given $H$, we can build a machine $L$ that has the characteristic halting function $D$. The machine
$L$ is nearly identical to $H$, so that $L(i)$ mimics
$H(i,i)$,  except that whenever $H(i,i)$ is about to
terminate with value $1$, $L(i)$ goes into an infinite loop and does not
terminate.

It is quite clear that we can build such a machine $L$ if $H$
exists. Hence this machine should be in our initial *enumeration of **all**
machines* (which we know is possible). But it cannot be since its
halting behavior $D$ corresponds to none of the machines enumerated.
Machine $L$ cannot exist, which implies that $H$ cannot
exist.

<sub>I deliberately mimicked the first proof and went into tiny
details</sub>

My feeling is that the steps come naturally in this way, especially
when one considers Cantor's proof as reasonably intuitive.

One first enumerates the litigious constructs. Then one takes and modifies the
diagonal as a convenient way of touching all of them to get an
unaccounted for behaviour, then gets a contradiction by exhibiting an
object that has the unaccounted for behaviour ... if some hypothesis
were to be true: existence of the enumeration for Cantor, and
existence of a computable halting oracle for Turing.

**Note:** To define the function $D$, we could replace the flipped
diagonal by any other characteristic halting function, different from
all the ones listed in $T$, that is computable (from the ones listed
in $T$, for example) provided a halting oracle is available. Then the machine $L$
would have to be constructed accordingly, to have $D$ as characteristic
halting function, and $L(i)$ would make use of the machine $H$, but
not mimic so directly $H(i,i)$. The choice of the diagonal makes it
much simpler.

### Comparison with the "other" proof

The function $L$ defined here is apparently the analog of the function
$D$ in the proof described in the question.

We only build it in such a way that it has a characteristic halting
function that corresponds to no Turing machine, and get directly a
contradiction from that. This gives us the freedom of not using the
diagonal (for what it is worth).

The idea of the "usual" proof seems to try to kill what I see
as a dead fish. It says: let's assume that $L$ is one of the machines
that were listed (i.e., all of them). Then it has an index $j_L$ in
that enumeration: $L=M_{j_L}$. Then if $L(j_L)$ halts, we have
$T[j_L,j_L]=H(j_L,j_L)=1$, so that $L(j_L)$ will loop by
construction. Conversely, if $L(j_L)$ does not halt, then
$T[j_L,j_L]=H(j_L,j_L)=0$ so that $L(j_L)$ will halt by construction.
Thus we have a contradiction.  But the contradiction results from the
way the characteristic halting function of $L$ was constructed,
and it seems a lot simpler just to say that $L$ cannot be a Turing
machine because it is constructed to have a characteristic halting
function that is not that of a Turing machine.

A side-point is that this usual proof would be a lot more painful if
we did not choose the diagonal, while the direct approach used above
has no problem with it. Whether that can be useful, I do not know.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! It seems that somehow you managed to go around the self-applying constructions that I found troublesome. Now I wonder why people found them necessary in the first place.

Comment: @user118967 I tried to underscore that using the diagonal is not
really important. All you want is to define a characteristic halting
function that is different from all those listed in the table, and
that is computable from those listed, provided we have a halting
oracle. There are infinitely many such characteristic halting
functions. Now that seems not so visible in the usual proof, and it
may be that some constructs of that proof seem arbitrary simply
because they are, like chosing the diagonal in the proof above.
It is only simple, not essential.

Comment: @user118967 I added and introduction that summarizes the analysis of the various
proofs. It complement the comparison between proofs (with and without
self application) that is given in the end. I do not know whether I
did away with diagonalization as asked **:)** (I think it would be
unfair to say so) but I do hint on how to do away with the obvious
diagonal. And the proof does not use self-application, which seems an
unnecessary, but slick looking, trick hiding what may seem a more important issue, the halting behavior.

Comment: @user118967 To answer your first comment, and after reading the most upvoted
answer, it seem that the main motivation is the link with the work of
Russell and Gödel. Now I have no idea whether it is really essential
for that purpose, and the self-applying constructions variant can
certainly be studied for the purpose, but I don't see the point of
imposing it on everyone. Furthermore, the more direct proof seems more
intuitive, and does give the tool to further analyse the self-applying
version. Why then?

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree with you on that.

Comment: This I've seen as the proof that the diagonal language $L_d$ (your $D$) isn't computable, a step towards the halting problem...

Answer (score 8):

There is also a proof of this fact that uses a different paradox, Berry's paradox, which I heard from Ran Raz.

Suppose that the halting problem were computable. Let $B(n)$ be the smallest natural number that cannot be computed by a C program of length $n$. That is, if $S(n)$ is the set of natural numbers computed by C programs of length $n$, then $B(n)$ is the smallest natural number not in $S(n)$.

Consider the following program:

1. Go over all C programs of length at most $n$.
2. For each such program, check if it halts; if it does, add it to a list $L$.
3. Output the first natural number not in $L$.

This is a program for computing $B(n)$. How large is this program? Encoding $n$ takes $O(\log n)$ characters, and the rest of the program doesn't depend on $n$, so in total the length is $O(\log n)$, say at most $C\log n$. Choose $N$ so that $C\log N \leq N$. Then our program, whose length is at most $N$, computes $B(N)$, contradicting the definition of $B(N)$.

The same idea can be used to prove Gödel's incompleteness theorems, as shown by [Kritchman and Raz](http://www.ams.org/notices/201011/rtx101101454p.pdf).

Comment: Perhaps it's in the paper I cite, or in the classic monograph Kolmogorov Complexity by Li and Vitányi.

Comment: By the way, do you think that this method provides an attack on the NP vs CoNP problem?

Comment: No. Such problems are beyond us at the moment.

Comment: "and the rest of the program doesn't depend on $n$" Why?

Comment: The parameter $n$ only appears once in the program. The *execution* of the program depends on $n$, but $n$ itself only appears once in its source code.

Answer (score 6):

There's a more general idea involved here called the "recursion theorem" that may be more intuitive: Turing machines can use their own description (and thus run themselves). More precisely, there is a theorem:

> For any Turing machine `T`, there is a Turing machine `R` that computes `R(x) = T(R;x)`.

If we had a Turing machine that could solve the halting problem, then using the idea described above, we can easily construct a variety of "liar" turing machines: e.g. in python-like notation,

```
def liar():
    if halts(liar):
        return not liar()
        # or we could do an infinite loop
    else:
        return True
```

The more complicated argument is essentially just trying to do this directly without appealing to the recursion theorem. That is, it's repeating a recipe for constructing "self-referential" functions. e.g. given a Turing machine `T`, here is one such recipe for constructing an `R` satisfying

```
R(x) = T(R; x)
```

First, define

```
S(M; x) = T(M(M; -); x)
```

where by `M(M; -)`, what I really mean is that we compute (using the description of `M`) and plug in a description of a Turing machine that, on input `y`, evaluates `M(M; y)`.

Now, we observe that if we plug `S` into itself

```
S(S; x) = T(S(S; -); x)
```

we get the duplication we want. So if we set

```
R = S(S; -)
```

then we have

```
R(x) = T(R; x)
```

as desired.

Comment: The first paragraph does not match the theorem you cite, which I know by the name of s-m-n theorem.

Comment: @Raphael: It's called the recursion theorem in my textbook. :( My brief attempt at google failed to turn up any alternative names.

Comment: No worries; maybe I understand you wrong, or there are different names for the same thing. That said, your sentence "Turing machines can use their own description" is not supported by the theorem you quote. In fact, I think it's wrong: if the function a TM computes depended on its index, what would all the infinitely many TMs that compute the same function look like?

Comment: Sorry, not following. Shouldn't $T$ be a *universal* TM? Also why does `liar` return `True` in the else case? Is it supposed to answer the question "does 'liar' halt?"? If so, why does is it ok for it to return `not liar()` in the first case? Shouldn't it be `False` (or infinite loop)?

Comment: @user: Nope: you're got the quantifiers wrong. The theorem is "for every $T$, there exists a $R$ such that $R(x) = T(R; x)$". You are thinking about "There exists a $T$ such that for every $R$, $R(x) = T(R; x)$.

Comment: @user: There are lots of liar functions one can make. It wasn't completely clear what *specific* liar was being constructed in the OP  (i.e. what "reverses the output" means). The liar I constructed outputs `true` if it doesn't halt, it outputs `false` if it halts and outputs `true`, and if outputs `true` if it halts and outputs `false`; a contradiction in all three cases.

Comment: ... although maybe I should add that the kinds of `T` we use the theorem for usually contain a universal Turing machine as a subroutine, since often when we write a program that computes `T(self, other inputs)`, it usually involves making recursive calls to `self`.

Comment: Not sure why you thought I got the quantifiers wrong. My question about $T$ being universal is because of the notation $T(R;x)$. My impression is that the `;` is used to indicate a Turing machine-input pair, which can only be the input to a *universal* Turing machine?

Comment: @user118967: I'm really confused about your notation then; $M_H$ isn't a universal Turing machine, and you used it there. I had assumed that was just your notation for encoding two inputs into single string, since people do things like that, and was following your lead. Normally I wouldn't have bothered with something like that and would just write $T(R, x)$ notating the application of $T$ like a bivariate function.

Comment: Just to make sure there isn't a crossed communication, I interpret "$T$ is a universal turing machine" to specifically mean a Turing machine where $T(R, x) = R(x)$ for every $R$ encoding a turing machine $R$ and every string $x$.

Comment: Yes, you are right the notation does not need to be used only for universal Turing machines, sorry. I will spend more time on your answer later. Thanks.

Comment: So, I came back, but did not manage to follow your argument. Why do we need the recursion theorem to construct the liar function? When I look at the liar function, to me it seems that all it requires is a 'halt' function (the hypothesis of the halting problem undecidability theorem that leads to a contradiction).

Comment: @user: The recursion theorem is what lets you put the "this" in "this statement is false" (well, "this function returns the negation of what this function returns"). I don't claim to mean you have to use the recursion theorem; you can always do an ad-hoc construction that is pulled out of thin air without motivation, and maybe there are methods of deriving a contradiction that aren't based on self-reference. My point is that the recursion theorem provides the motivation for the unintuitive construction.

Answer (score 5):

the Turing proof is quite similar to Cantors proof that the cardinality of reals ("uncountable") is larger than the cardinality of the rationals ("countable") because they cannot be put into 1-1 correspondence but this is not noted/ emphasized in very many references (does anyone know any?). (iirc) a CS prof once showed this years ago in class (not sure where he got it himself). in Cantors proof one can imagine a grid with horizontal dimension the *n*<sup>th</sup> digit of the number and the vertical dimension the *n*<sup>th</sup> number of the set.

the Turing halting proof construction is quite similar except that the contents of the table are Halt/ Nonhalt for 1/ 0 instead, and the horizontal axis is *n*<sup>th</sup> input, and the vertical axis is *n*<sup>th</sup> computer program. in other words the combination of computer programs and inputs are countable but the infinite table/ array is uncountable based on a universal machine simulator construction that can "flip" a halting to a nonhalting case assuming a halting detector machine exists (hence *reductio ad absurdam*).

some evidence that Turing had Cantors construction partly in mind is that his same paper with the halting proof talks about computable numbers as (along the lines of) real numbers with computable digits.

Comment: addendum, there is indeed a very "intuitive" way to view undecidability but it requires a lot of higher math to grasp (ie intuition of a neophyte is much different than intuition of an expert). mathematicians do consider the halting problem and godels thm identical proofs via a Lawvere fixed point theorem, but this is an advanced fact not much accessible to undergraduates "yet". see [halting problem, uncomputable sets, common math problem?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/halting-problem-uncomputable-sets-common-mathematical-proof) [cstheory.se] & also linked post for refs

Answer (score 3):

At this point it is worth noting the work by [Emil Post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Leon_Post) who is (justly) credited with being a co-discoverer of the basic results of computability, though sadly was published too late to be considered a co-discoverer of the solution to the [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem). He certainly participated in the elaboration of the so-called [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Post was motivated by very philosophical considerations, namely the *theoretical* limitations of the human ability to compute, or even get precise answers in a *consistent* manner. He devised a system, now called [Post canonical systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system), the details of which are unimportant, which he claimed could be used to solve *any problem which can be solved soely by manipulation of symbols*. Interestingly, he explicitly considered mental states to be part of the "memory" explicitly, so it is likely that he at least considered his model of computation to be a model of human thought in it's entirety.

The Entscheidungsproblem considers the possibility of using such a means of computation to say, determine the theoremhood of any proposition expressible in the system of the [Principia Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica). But the PM was a system explicitly designed to be able to represent all of mathematical reasoning, and, by extension (at least at the time, when [Logicism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicism) was still in vogue) all of human reasoning!

It's therefore very unsurprising then, to turn the attention of such a system to the Post canonical systems themselves, just as the human mind, via the works of Frege, Russel and logicians of the turn of the century had turned their attention to the reasoning faculty of the human mind itself.

So it is clear at this point, that self-reference, or the ability of systems to describe themselves, was a rather natural subject in the early 1930s. In fact, David Hilbert was hoping to "bootstrap" mathematical reasoning itself, by providing a formal description of all of human mathematics, which then could be mathematically proven to be consistent itself!

Once the step of using a formal system to reason about itself is obtained, it's a hop and a skip away from the usual self-referential paradoxes (which have a [pretty old history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox)).

Since all the statements in *Principia* are presumed to be "true" in some metaphysical sense, and the *Principia* can express

> program `p` returns result `true` on input `n`

if a program exists to decide all theorems in that system, it is quite simple to directly express the liar's paradox:

> this program always lies.

can be expressed by

> The program `p` always returns the opposite of what the principia mathematica say `p` will return.

The difficulty is building the program `p`. But at this point, it's rather natural to consider the more general sentence

> The program `p` always returns the opposite of what the PM say `q` will return.

for some arbitrary `q`. But it's easy to build `p(q)` for any given `q`! Just compute what PM predicts it will output, and return the opposite answer. We can't just replace `q` by `p` at this point though, since `p` takes `q` as input, and `q` does not (it takes no input). Let's change our sentence so that `p` *does* take input:

> The program `p` returns the opposite of what PM says `q(r)` will return.

Arg! But now `p` takes 2 pieces of input: `q` and `r`, whereas `q` only takes 1. But wait: we want `p` in both places anyways, so `r` is not a *new* piece of information, but just the same piece of data again, namely `q`! This is the critical observation.

So we finally get

> The program `p` returns the opposite of what PM says `q(q)` will return.

Let's forget about this silly "PM says" business, and we get

> The program `p(q)` returns the opposite of what `q(q)` will return.

This is a legitimate program *provided we have a program that always tells us what `q(q)` returns*. But now that we have our program `p(q)`, we can replace `q` by `p` and get our liar's paradox.