# Does the Linz Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly transition to its final reject state?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, halting-problem, simulation

```
// Linz Turing machine H --- H applied to ⟨H⟩ 
H.q0 ⟨H⟩ ⟨H⟩ ⊢* H.qy   // H applied to ⟨H⟩ halts
H.q0 ⟨H⟩ ⟨H⟩ ⊢* H.qn   // H applied to ⟨H⟩ does not halt
Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?
```

Of the infinite set of implementations of H every one that transitions to H.qy derives an answer consistent with the behavior of H.

**When we append an infinite loop to the H.qy state we derive Ȟ**

```
Ȟ.q0 ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⊢* Ȟ.qy ∞ // Ȟ applied to ⟨Ȟ⟩ halts
Ȟ.q0 ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⊢* Ȟ.qn   // Ȟ applied to ⟨Ȟ⟩ does not halt 
Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?
```

Of the infinite set of implementations of Ȟ none of them derives an answer consistent with the behavior of Ȟ.

This is because the question:
**Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?**
is self-contradictory thus incorrect question for Ȟ.

Yes/no questions intentionally defined to have no correct yes/no answer are incorrect questions. The inability to correctly answer an incorrect question places no actual limit on anyone or anything.

**Two PhD computer science professors agree with this view:**

E C R Hehner. **Objective and Subjective Specifications** WST Workshop on Termination, Oxford. 2018 July 18.
See [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hehner/OSS.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehehner/OSS.pdf)

Bill Stoddart. **The Halting Paradox**
20 December 2017
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.05340
arXiv:1906.05340 [cs.LO]

## Prior question

**Applying a Simulating Halt Decider to the Linz Halting Problem Proof**

A simulating (at least partial) halt decider correctly predicts whether or not its correctly simulated input can possibly reach its own final state and halt. It does this by correctly recognizing several non-halting behavior patterns in a finite number of steps of correct simulation. Inputs that do terminate are simply simulated until they complete.

The Linz text indicates that Ĥ is defined on the basis of prepending and appending states to the original Linz H, (assumed halt decider) thus is named embedded_H.

(q0) is prepended to H to copy the ⟨Ĥ⟩ input of Ĥ. The transition from (qa) to (qb) is the conventional infinite loop appended to the (qy) accept state of embedded_H.
⊢* indicates an arbitrary number of moves.

The Linz term “move” means a state transition and its corresponding tape head action {move_left, move_right, read, write}. Ĥ is applied to its own machine description ⟨Ĥ⟩.

Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qy ∞ 
Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qn

[image]

When Ĥ is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ 
(q0) The input ⟨Ĥ⟩ is copied then transitions to (qx)
(qx) embedded_H is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ (input and copy) 
which simulates ⟨Ĥ⟩ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ which begins at its own (q0) to repeat the process.

This process continues to repeat until embedded_H recognizes the repeating pattern and aborts its simulation of ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩. embedded_H can see the same repeating pattern that we see.

**computation that halts…** “the Turing machine will halt whenever it enters a final state” (Linz:1990:234)

## Every "rebuttal" simply ignores this key fact

**⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly simulated by embedded_H cannot possibly reach its own simulated final state of ⟨Ĥ.qn⟩ and halt in any finite number of steps of correct simulation.**

**Linz, Peter 1990.** An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata.
Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company. (317-320)

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127422/discussion-on-question-by-polcott-does-the-linz-h-specify-a-computation-that-nev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refutation of the Peter Linz Halting Problem proof**

The following shows how Linz H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ gets the right answer because Linz Ĥ.H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ gets the wrong answer

H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* H.qy // Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ halts
H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* H.qn // Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ does not halt

**Criterion Measure**
H is assumed to be a simulating termination analyzer that aborts the simulation of any input that would cause its own non-termination and returns NO. Otherwise H always returns YES.

Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.Hq0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.Hqy ∞ // Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ halts
Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.Hq0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.Hqn // Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ does not halt

Execution trace of Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩
(a) Ĥ.q0 The input ⟨Ĥ⟩ is copied then transitions to Ĥ.H
(b) Ĥ.H applied ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ (input and copy) simulates ⟨Ĥ⟩ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩
(c) which begins at its own simulated ⟨Ĥ.q0⟩ to repeat the process
**Same execution trace even when infinite loop is removed**

It is true that Ĥ.H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ must transition to Ĥ.Hqn to prevent its own infinite execution. It is true that this makes Ĥ ⟨Ĥ⟩ halt. This entails  that H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ would be correct to transition to H.qy.

When Ĥ.H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ and H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly apply the above criteria then Ĥ.H
⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ would transition to Ĥ.Hqn and H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ would transition to H.qy

**No one has refuted any of the above reasoning**

Answer (score 8):

This is an answer to an attempt at understanding a previous version of the question, and is no longer relevant to the latest question.

---

Your question is: What happens when you use a simulating halt decider and (...)?

The answer is: You can't.  The question has a faulty premise.  A simulating halt decider does not exist, so there is no meaningful answer to the question.

---

I'll highlight your definition.  You propose the following definition:

> A simulating (at least partial) halt decider H is a UTM that has been adapted to decide whether or not its input halts. It does this by simulating its input and examining the behavior of this simulated input.

(I presume this should be interpreted as saying that, to count as a simulating halt decider, the UTM must always correctly decide whether or not its input halts, for all possible inputs.)

The problem is: there does not exist any UTM that successfully acts as a simulating halt decider on all inputs.

You can add all the conditions and requirements you want to a definition. The definition remains valid.  But there is no guarantee that there exists any object that meets the conditions of the definition.  That has to be separately verified.

It sounds like you think that there does exist such a UTM that would qualify as a simulating halt decider.  However, your intuition is faulty.  I know it's easy to identify some patterns that, if they arise during execution, allow us to determine whether the input will halt.  However, those patterns will never be comprehensive.  No matter how many patterns you write down, there will always be some inputs that aren't handled by any of those patterns.

Those of us who have studied complexity theory already know this, because there is a theorem that proves it.  High-level statements such as "Certain patterns of behavior such as infinite loops and infinite recursion can be recognized." is not likely to be effective at persuading anyone to the contrary, because we know there are also other kinds of behavior that won't be recognized; yet such language is too vague and imprecise to allow us to give you specific examples to help you see that fact concretely.

---

If you'd like to pump your intuition, you can find some examples of programs where no one knows whether they halt or not: [What are the simplest examples of programs that we do not know whether they terminate?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44869/755), [What are very short programs with unknown halting status?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59344/755).  If you study them, perhaps it will give you a better sense why these programs might fail to halt (they might run forever) without ever entering any loop, or even matching "pattern" that you can write down.  (More specifically, for any pattern or list of patterns you have in mind, there might be some input that fails to halt but doesn't match any of those patterns.)

---

If you want an analogy, I find your assertions to come off (to me) as similar to the following made-up conversation:

Polly: Let's define an "awesome circle" to be a circle whose radius $r$ and circumference $C$ satisfy the relationship $C=8r+1$.  What would happen if we replaced the 4 tires on my car with objects that have an "awesome circle" shape?

Conan: You can't.  No such object exists.  The question is meaningless.

Polly: Sure, but assume $H$ is an awesome circle, and I put it on my car.  What happens?

Conan: You can't.  $H$ doesn't exist.  The assumption is false.

Polly: But my $H$ is defined to be awesome.  An awesome circle is one that has been adapted so that $C=8r+1$.

Conan: You can't.  You can't adapt a circle that way.

Polly: I have superior knowledge of round shapes.  Anyone with my experience with round shapes would see immediately how to adapt a circle in that way.

I hope you can see how this exchange is a bit absurd and Conan would tire of it quickly and not have any interest in continuing the conversation.  Of course, if Conan knows some mathematics, then he immediately knows that all circles satisfy the relationship $C=2\pi r$; since there is no solution to the system of equations $C=2 \pi r$, $C=8r+1$ with $r \ge 0$, any mathematician would immediately know that no "awesome circle" can exist, so there is not much point in continuing such a conversation.

This is how your attempts to address this topic come off to me.  Your assertions remind me of Polly's assertions  (Polly's awesome circle = your simulating halt decider; Conan = any computer scientist who has studied decidability).  Hopefully this helps you better understand the reactions you are getting and use it to help you focus your future studies.

Comment: "(I presume this should be interpreted as saying that, to count as a simulating halt decider, the UTM must always correctly decide whether or not its input halts, for all possible inputs)." I already stipulated that this assumption is incorrect when I said ***"at least partial halt decider".*** My goal is limited to refuted the conventional proofs. My goal is not to prove that halting is decidable. A partial halt decider exists even if it only decides one input.

Comment: @polcott, OK.  That wasn't clear to me.  If that's what you mean, then the question isn't answerable in its current form.  You ask what is the behavior of <<something with $H$>> but you haven't specified $H$.  You listed some conditions you want us to assume $H$ satisfies, but you  haven't identified a single TM $H$.  There remain many possibilities for what $H$ could be.  So, there's not enough information to answer the question; the behavior will likely depend on which specific $H$ we are looking at.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what kind of an answer you'd be looking for, when you ask "What is the behavior".  Do you want an execution trace?  An English description of what it does?  If so, what do you want to be in that English description?

Comment: I am saying that under the conditions that I specify when Ĥ is applied to its own Turing machine description I see an infinitely repeating that never halts unless the simulation is aborted. ***Do you see this same infinitely repeating pattern?*** That is the essence of my whole question.

Comment: @polcott, I don't see that  asked in the question.  It's hard to answer questions if I have to guess what is being asked.

Comment: I have finally simplified the question enough that it can be properly answered. Your answer no longer applies to this simplified question.

Comment: **It is an easily verified fact that:** Every counter-example input to the halting theorem D cannot possibly reach its own simulated final state in any finite number of steps when correctly simulated by simulating halt decider H.

Comment: >>>(I presume this should be interpreted as saying that, to count as a simulating halt decider, the UTM must always correctly decide whether or not its input halts, for all possible inputs.)<<< You did not bother to notice the term "partial halt decider" ???

Comment: "(I presume this should be interpreted as saying that, to count as a simulating halt decider, the UTM must always correctly decide whether or not its input halts, for all possible inputs.)" In other words you are "interpreting" "partial" to mean {complete}, that is like "interpreting" "huge" to mean {tiny}. **I updated my answer so that it is much more clear (please see below).**

Comment: >>>Your question is: What happens when you use a simulating halt decider and (...)?<<< **change that to simulating termination analyzer**  It turns out that the input only contradicts its own internal termination analyzer thus does not contradict the external H

Answer (score 4):

In response to an earlier version:

You have misunderstood their proof, which is not very well presented (imho); but you also seem to have cut off the end, where they establish the contradiction.

They do not state anywhere that $M$ is simulated, at all.

$\hat H$ simulates $H'$ and $H'$ simulates $H$. Now, $H$ is *assumed* -- towards a contradiction -- to be *decider*. which means it always terminates after finitely many steps. No assumption is made on how it solves the halting problem -- which is the point, of course, because only so can be disprove *all* candidates for $H$ by leading the assumption to a contradiction!

So we simulate $H$ which always terminates -- no infinitely nested simulation is happening.

Your intuition is not wrong, though, even though you seem to be missing the corner cases: you'd *need* something like "infinitely nested simulation" to solve the halting problem -- something that doesn't work. Because it's impossible.

---

> When we hypothesize that the halt decider embedded in Ĥ is simply a Universal Turing Machine (UTM) does this define a computation that never halts when Ĥ is applied to its own Turing machine description?

There are infinitely many UTMs. Without further assumptions, we just don't know what any arbitrary one of those does on its own encoding.

Comment: A simulating (at least partial) halt decider does correctly decide that Ĥ applied to its own Turing machine description correctly decides that its input would not halt (see Figure 12.4 above). It is simpler to use my notational conventions where Ĥ is a single machine with named internal states. Simpler notational conventions prevent confusion.

Comment: "They do not state anywhere that M is simulated, at all." The proof leaves open how H is defined when it specifies the ⊢* wildcard state transitions. We analyze the behavior of Ĥ applied to its own Turing machine description ŵ.  When the embedded halt decider bases its decision on simulating its input an infinitely repeating pattern is derived. When computations have Infinitely repeating patterns we know that these computations never halt.

Comment: @polcott  You don't get to make assumptions on how H works.

Comment: Yes you do that is what the ⊢* wildcard state transition encoding means. One is free to define H in an unlimited number of different ways including defining H on the basis of a UTM.

Comment: No: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141080/what-happens-when-the-peter-linz-h-is-a-simulating-halt-decider-and-%c4%a4-is-applied/141115?noredirect=1#comment297264_141115 Hard as it is, at some point you'll have to reconsider the idea that  you acually haven't understood the proof.

Comment: I spent 12,000 hours on this and you only spent about 20 minutes.  I spent 3000 hours making an actual halt decider and the x86utm operating system that implements the Linz H_Hat showing exactly how it decides that its input is not a halting computation when it is applied to itself. To understand what I am saying you must do much more than glance at a few of my words before forming your rebuttal.

Comment: I had daily reviews from several reviewers for six months none of them ever found any actual error.

Comment: There is no material here to spend more time on. I'm sorry you wasted all that time.

Comment: By the way: even _if_ you managed to come up with some machine that can solve its own halting problem, that does not solve _the_ halting problem.

Comment: Yes I know that. My maximum scope is to refute all the conventional halting problem proofs.

Comment: "So we simulate H which always terminates -- no infinitely nested simulation is happening." Not at all. When H recognizes what would be infinitely nested simulation it aborts its simulation of this input and halts.

Comment: @polcott Does this help? https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/112230/1329

Comment: "When H recognizes what would be infinitely nested simulation it aborts its simulation of this input and halts" -- No. You don't know anything about H.

Comment: I have finally simplified the question enough that it can be properly answered. Your answer no longer applies to this simplified question.

Comment: **It turns out that the input only contradicts its own internal termination analyzer and does not contradict the external H.**

Answer (score -1):

When a simulating halt decider correctly simulates N steps of its input it derives the exact same N steps that a pure UTM would derive because it is itself a UTM with extra features.

Because of this we can know that the first N steps of ⟨Ĥ⟩ simulated by embedded_H are the actual behavior that ⟨Ĥ⟩ presents to embedded_H for these same N steps.

**computation that halts…** “the Turing machine will halt whenever it enters a final state” (Linz:1990:234)

**Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qy ∞**
**Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qn**

[image]

**When Ĥ is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩**
(Ĥ.q0) The input ⟨Ĥ⟩ is copied then transitions to embedded_H
embedded_H is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ (input and copy)
which simulates ⟨Ĥ⟩ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ 
**which begins at its own simulated ⟨Ĥ.q0⟩ to repeat the process.**

When we see (after the above N steps) that ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly simulated by embedded_H cannot possibly reach its simulated final state of ⟨Ĥ.qn⟩ in any finite number of steps of correct simulation then we have conclusive proof that ⟨Ĥ⟩ presents non-halting behavior to embedded_H.

Therefore when embedded_H aborts the simulation of its input and transitions to its own final state of Ĥ.qn it is merely reporting this verified fact.